# Is there any command in iOS like purge?

Tags: ios, memory

In MacOsx, we can clean memory through Terminal, like this page show http://www.electrictoolbox.com/purge-free-inactive-memory-mac-osx/  We can enter "purge" commandLine in Terminal.
Then, in a non-jailbreak iOS, how can we do that programmatically?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically within your application, or for a utility that can do this? If the latter, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: Ooh, boy.  The whole point of like half of iOS' service layer is dedicated to memory management, and you want to do it's job?  Good luck (because the API is probably intensely private).

Comment: @Brad Larson I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: @CodaFi I only want to know, Can I do that in my code?

Comment: Are you asking in a possible jailbreak context? If not, this level of the OS is just not something that's visible to you.

Comment: @BenZotto In a non-jailbreak iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purge` is not the tool you think it is. It flushes the disk cache. This is something you typically never ever want to do in practice. It certainly does not "clean memory". The purpose of `purge` is to simulate cold boot conditions so you can do performance testing.

That said, no, you can't do this on iOS.

Comment: In my comprehension, "purge" can flush disk cache and memory cache.   And, if the answer is no. Is there any method can implement this fuction like purge in MacOsx do?

Comment: @SakuragiHanamichi: What do you mean by "memory cache"? `purge` flushes the disk cache, which is of course an in-memory cache, that's used to speed up disk I/O. There is quite literally no reason for you to ever use this command unless you are trying to do performance testing that needs to simulate cold boot conditions.

Comment: thanks. I saw this app(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memory-100/id554435411?mt=8) can do this. And I don't think it's a fake!

Comment: @SakuragiHanamichi: That app almost certainly simply allocates enough memory to cause the system to start purging background apps, and then deallocates that memory. But don't think this means you should do it yourself! These apps are pretty bogus. The system already frees up new memory when you need it by terminating suspended apps, and that's all this app is triggering.